# How to scroll to each option list and back to the top to start again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list with 5 elements and I want this scroll automatically to each element every 3 seconds, and after finishes the last element return to the first element and start again. This is my example.

```js
var height = $(".list li:first-child").outerHeight();
    
setInterval(function(){ 

        $('.list').animate({
            scrollTop: 58
        }, 500);



}, 3000);
```

```css
.list{width: 200px;height: 180px;overflow: auto;list-style: none;padding-left: 0px;}
ul.list li{padding:20px 0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">

    <li>Option 01</li>
    <li>Option 02</li>
    <li>Option 03</li>
    <li>Option 04</li>
    <li>Option 05</li>

</ul>
```

As you can see, the list only scroll to the second element and then stops. How can I fix it?

I'd like your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it as described you'll need to know how many items you have and use the height of the item you already found but weren't using. Then you'll need to track the current count/step and increase it as long as it's less than the total length of items or return to 0 if not.

However, there's a problem where no scroll will happen for any items that are near the bottom since there's nowhere for the container to scroll. You could allow additional space for the scroll by adding space below the last li like I did but it looks a little strange.

```js
var height = $(".list li:first-child").outerHeight();
// Get the number of items
var itemLength = $(".list li").length
// Set the currentItem to 0
var currentItem = 0
// Set the initial scroll to height so the first interval goes to item[1]
var scroll = height

setInterval(function() {

  $('.list').animate({
    scrollTop: scroll
  }, 500);
  // Increase the step or return to 0 if it's greater than the length of items
  if (currentItem < itemLength - 1) {
    currentItem ++
  } else {
    currentItem = 0
  }
  // Set the scroll based on above changes
  scroll = currentItem * height

}, 3000);
```

```css
.list {
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

ul.list li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
li:last-of-type {
margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">

  <li>Option 01</li>
  <li>Option 02</li>
  <li>Option 03</li>
  <li>Option 04</li>
  <li>Option 05</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you just have a constant scroll value of 58, due to which it just scrolls down with a 'scroll value' of 58, and then stops.

What you need to do is that first scroll down by 58, wait for 3 seconds and then again scroll down by 58 more, and so on, and once you reach the bottom, which comes after 2 scrolls in your case (giving a total scroll value of 58 + 58 = 116), you need to give a scroll value of 0, so that it scrolls back up again.

The following code does so:

```js
let scrollValue = 0
setInterval(function(){ 
        scrollValue < 116 ? scrollValue += 58 : scrollValue = 0;
        // console.log(`scrollValue: ${scrollValue}`);
        $('.list').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollValue
        }, 500);



}, 3000);
```

```css
.list{
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
ul.list li{
    padding:20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>Option 01</li>
  <li>Option 02</li>
  <li>Option 03</li>
  <li>Option 04</li>
  <li>Option 05</li>
</ul>
```

What I have done here is defined a variable `scrollValue`, which defines how much to scroll down. It is 0 initially, and every time the function to animate is called, it gets increased by 58, and if that value reaches 116 (since you have to scroll down twice), `scrollValue` becomes 0, so that scrolls you back up.